# What are the background threads in active thread count in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I am using an ExecutorService with 10 fixed threads.

```
  ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
```

When I tried to find out the number of the threads using

```
  System.out.println(Thread.activeCount());
```

the output varied from 11 to 15.

I know that one of those threads is the main thread.

But what are the other threads?

Comment: The garbage collector might use threads. Depending on the libraries/frameworks that you use they might use threads too, but you didn't specify anything about this.

Answer (score 3):

There is a handful of threads in Java that run in the background e.g. Finalizer for calling `finalize()` methods. You can print them by looking at the most parent [ThreadGroup](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadGroup.html):

```
ThreadGroup group = Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup();
while (group.getParent() != null) {
  group = group.getParent();
}
Thread[] threads = new Thread[group.activeCount()];
group.enumerate(threads);
Arrays.stream(threads).forEach(System.out::println);
```

it will output something like

```
Thread[Reference Handler,10,system]
Thread[Finalizer,8,system]
Thread[Signal Dispatcher,9,system]
Thread[Attach Listener,5,system]
Thread[main,5,main]
Thread[Monitor Ctrl-Break,5,main]
```

In your example `Thread.activeCount()` is a shorthand for `Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup().activeCount()` so you are looking at the top-most, current ThreadGroup.